# Get Columns as Month Name in a specific year in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server:

1. `Employee` (id, empid, empname) and
2. `EmpSales` (id, empid, billdtae, sale)

The `EmpSales` table has employee sales data for many years.

My query is, I want `Empid` as 1st column, `EmpName` as 2nd column, and all the month's name as subsequent columns like January, February, March for a particular year and the sum of sales corresponding to employee and month as data.

I have tried and searched a lot but could not get to the correct solution. I can get `Empid` and `EmpName` with the following query but the rest solution is what I am looking for.

```
SELECT S.empid, E.empname
FROM empsale S
INNER JOIN employee E ON S.empid = E.empid 
WHERE YEAR(S.bill_date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY S.empid, E.empname 
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT,S.empid)
```

This query returns only `empid` and `empname` but what is want is like this

[image]

It will be a great help if anyone can reply me with the correct query/answer or provide any better solution to it.

Comment: Sample data and expected results will help us help you, however, this is known as a "pivot", a cross tab or conditional aggregation.

Comment: well I was also wondering for the same answer, but seriously, I have never used pivot in SQL. I am very well aware of pivot in Excel.

Comment: is there any way you can provide me a query for the same. and also tell me how to give sample data.

Comment: I can't show you how to answer the question without sample data and expected results, no. See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055/2029983)

Comment: The first step is to calculate the values you need for each month within the year of interest. Once you have that working, you can then pivot rows to columns - examples of which you can find by searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straightforward way to do this without having to resort to PIVOT and dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @Employee table ( empid int, empname varchar(50), id int IDENTITY(1,1) );
INSERT INTO @Employee VALUES
    ( 1000, 'Bill Gates' ), ( 1001, 'Elon Musk' );

DECLARE @EmpSales table ( empid int, bill_date date, sale int );
INSERT INTO @EmpSales VALUES
    ( 1000, '01/01/2020', 100 ), ( 1000, '01/15/2020', 100 ), ( 1000, '02/15/2020', 50 ), ( 1000, '04/01/2020', 25 );

SELECT
    e.empid, e.empname, s.*
FROM @Employee e
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT
        ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, n.bill_date ) = 'January' THEN n.sale ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS [Jan],
        ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, n.bill_date ) = 'February' THEN n.sale ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS [Feb],
        ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, n.bill_date ) = 'March' THEN n.sale ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS [Mar],
        ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, n.bill_date ) = 'April' THEN n.sale ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS [Apr],
        ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, n.bill_date ) = 'May' THEN n.sale ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS [May],
        ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, n.bill_date ) = 'June' THEN n.sale ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS [Jun],
        ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, n.bill_date ) = 'July' THEN n.sale ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS [Jul],
        ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, n.bill_date ) = 'August' THEN n.sale ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS [Aug],
        ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, n.bill_date ) = 'September' THEN n.sale ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS [Sep],
        ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, n.bill_date ) = 'October' THEN n.sale ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS [Oct],
        ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, n.bill_date ) = 'November' THEN n.sale ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS [Nov],
        ISNULL( SUM( CASE WHEN DATENAME( month, n.bill_date ) = 'December' THEN n.sale ELSE 0 END ), 0 ) AS [Dec]
    FROM @EmpSales AS n
    WHERE
        n.empid = e.empid
        AND YEAR( n.bill_date ) = YEAR( GETDATE() )

) AS s
ORDER BY
    e.empid;
```

Returns

```
+-------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| empid |  empname   | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Aug | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec |
+-------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1000 | Bill Gates | 200 |  50 |   0 |  25 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
|  1001 | Elon Musk  |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |   0 |
+-------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: wow, So nice of you. you are awesome. This is actually what I want for my desired result, I don't know in what words I should thank you. However, with the clue in the previous answer, I searched for Pivot in SQL and I managed to achieve the same result after watching a video tutorial from 'wise owl' SQL programming. I will put the code.

Comment: sir, there is one slight change I would like to know how to apply in this query. suppose there are 100 employees in the employee table but only 30 employees were in the emsales table. According to the query above it displays all the employees. I want it like to display only employees in the empales table should be in the result. I mean to say those employees who have not done any sale should not be in the final result.

Comment: Change OUTER APPLY to CROSS APPLY.

Answer (score 2):

I have achieved the result with the following query.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      S.empid as Empid,
      E.empname as Employee,
      SUM(S.saleamt) as SaleAmt,
      DATENAME(MM, s.bill_date) as slmnth
    FROM
      empsale S
      INNER JOIN employee E ON S.empid = E.empid
    WHERE
      YEAR(S.bill_date) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    GROUP BY
      S.empid,
      E.empname,
      DATENAME(MM, s.bill_date)
  ) as bd PIVOT (
    SUM(SaleAmt) FOR slmnth in (
      [January],
      [February],
      [March],
      [May],
      [June],
      [July],
      [August],
      [September],
      [October],
      [November]
    )
  ) AS pvtbl
```